# portably perform field-splitting but not other expansions

Tags: shell, wildcards

I used to use unquoted expansion `$variable` when `variable` stored compiler flags, but I learned recently that glob metacharacters like `*` and `?` contained in `variable` are still expanded, e.g.

```
$ f='*'
$ echo $f
foo.bash
```

Is there a portable way to just perform field splitting without globbing besides `set -f` .

The most explicit way I can come up with to do this in bash is to define a `read_words` function like so, which populates an array name with the contents of a string passed in as an argument and then uses `${arr[@]}` to expand the string.

```
#!/bin/bash

count() {
  printf '%s\n' "$#"
}


read_words() {
  IFS=$' \t\n' read -a "$1" <<< "$2"
  return 0
}

read_words arr 'a b *'
count "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: Why not just store your flags in an array from the start?

Comment: @Jesse_b ... that's a good point. I try to avoid using bash-specific features in ways that can't easily be removed, but that might not be worth the trouble.

Comment: Duh, sorry.  True arrays are not as portable.

Comment: I'm confused why `set -f` isn't a good answer.  Are you concerned about the other expansions (brace, command, tilde, etc)?

Comment: @JeffSchaller `set -f` can cause problems if the script is `source`d unless the entire script is wrapped in a subshell. It's more state to keep in your head when spot-checking a script and (slightly) harder to write a mechanical check for. I'm concerned about the other expansions too; I only want to split on whitespace. ... It might be impossible to do this in a convenient way without `set -f` or arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set -f` is the most convenient way to get field splitting without globbing.

In `bash`, you can test whether a shell option is already set with the `-o` test. You may therefore do this:

```
if [ ! -o noglob ]; then
    set -f
    trap 'set +f' RETURN
fi
```

This would detect the state of the `noglob` shell option (the long name for `set -f`).  If it is not set, it is set and a `RETURN` trap is installed.  The trap will unset the `noglob` shell option when the script is done, *if the script is sourced*.  If the script is not sourced, the trap will do nothing.

Interesting note: A sourced script is very much like a shell function.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, you make the `set` options (contents of `$-`) local to a function with `local -`. Or you could run the part requiring `set -f` in a subshell, which should be portable.

```
countwords() { local -; set -f; set -- $1; echo "$#"; }
countwords "a b *"
```

or

```
countwords() ( set -f; set -- $1; echo "$#"; )
countwords "a b *"
```